# Missing \varepsilon symbol using unicode-math and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I like using Unicode symbols together with XeLaTeX, especially in mathematical documents, as it improves code readability. However there is a problem with the ɛ symbol. This should be mapped to `\varepsilon`, but as you can see from the result below, this symbol only produces a blank. Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    $ϵ,ɛ,\epsilon,\varepsilon$
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Image of missing epsilon]

Comment: I'm not sure it really improves code readability. `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character you're typing is not an epsilon, but U+025B LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E; what you want is ε (U+03B5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$ϵ,ε,\epsilon,\varepsilon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks! This seems to be a bug in the latex-completions package for the Atom editor then. It replaces \varepsilon with U+025B LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E.